# Why does it say that https: // fatal: Too many arguments?

Tags: git, github, https, git-clone

why do you give me this error? , I tried everything they answered in this stack over flow and nothing came from what they say
[Git fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53988638/11687151)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use english language.

`git clone` takes only one (optional 2) argument. You have 4.

Try `git clone https://github.com/DarthMoulByte/unity-cache-server.git`.
If you want to specify the target folder which contains spaces you have to escape spaces like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/DarthMoulByte/unity-cache-server.git Unity\ CacheServe\ v6
```

On windows cmd you do it like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/DarthMoulByte/unity-cache-server.git "Unity CacheServe v6"
```

Comment: scape spaces ?, i not understand this

Comment: if you are reading the image, you can tell that you already try it because the message that feeds back says that https is not recognized

Comment: if it can show that it works by capturing it in a gif image, I know if my system is bad or it is a general fault and it can not be cloned

Comment: I assume you want to clone the repo into folder called `Unity CacheServe v6`. Therefore your destination folder contains spaces. They have to be escaped with a backslash. Otherwise your shell cannot know if it's a new argument or a part of the previous. Try this `git clone https://github.com/DarthMoulByte/unity-cache-server.git Unity\ CacheServe\ v6`. If you are on Windows try `git clone https://github.com/DarthMoulByte/unity-cache-server.git "Unity CacheServe v6"`