# fatal protocol '"git'. I am unable to use git http request on my Mac Big Sur. SSH clones work fine but http returns this error below

Tags: git, flutter, macos, github

Whenever I want to clone a repo with my mac, http urls dont work but SSHs do. This has prevented to compile a required application in the last two weeks.

```
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air ~ % mkdir clones 
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air ~ % cd clones
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air clones % git clone https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class.git --progress --verbose
Cloning into 'PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class'...
fatal: protocol '”git' is not supported
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air clones % which git
git: aliased to /usr/local/opt/git@2.19.0/bin/git
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air clones % git --version
git version 2.19.0
chris@Chriss-MacBook-Air clones %
```

When I use the clone command on HTTPS, I get this error. It is kind of peculiar because I havent seen any sources or similar errors.

I have tried multiple versions of git, even the latest version 2.35.1

Thanks :)

Comment: Run `git config --list --show-origin` and look for `insteadOf` entries.

Comment: Please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988638/git-fatal-protocol-https-is-not-supported \