having an error in git while pushing the project on git remote it says "fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported"
i first ran this command which worked perfectly fine
it shows already exist cause i ran the command twice
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/chaudharidhara2781/tatvasoft_internship
error: remote origin already exists.


then i ran another command that shows error
$ git push -u origin main
fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported


i was expecting it to run smoothly
i tried deleting and recreating repo
adding some files in repo as i show somewhere empty repo might show error

Possible (probable?) duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53988638/2422776

If the URL for your origin is set incorrectly, you can update it with git remote set-url origin https://github.com/.... This will update the origin URL, then you can try your push again.
